# Add prefix to route using apache2 mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, symfony

I'm trying to use apache2's mod_rewrite to add a prefix to all my routes in my symfony2 2.1 project.

Let's say my symfony2 project's root is in /var/www/ProjectFrontEnd.

What I want to achieve is to let the user access the project using http://www.mydomain.com/Project

I have set up this in my virtual host:

```
    DocumentRoot var/www/ProjectFrontEnd

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/Project/(.*)$ /var/www/ProjectFrontEnd/web/app.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I look at the rewrite log, I can see that the route is rewritten as I expect (`rewrite '/Project/' -> '/var/www/ProjectFrontEnd/web/app.php/'`) but I get a 404 error from symfony and the log says something along the line of `request.ERROR: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /Project/" (uncaught exception)`

I don't understand why symfony2 still uses the non-rewritten url...

I'd like to specify that prefixing my routes in symfony's routing.yml is not an option.

Is what I want possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

In this way it's not possible, cause symfony handles every rewrite as a complete route.

You can simply use the `prefix` in your `app/config/routing.yml`. I know it's neccesary for every route import to add it, but the easiest and robust way.

```
acme_user:
    resource: "@AcmeUserBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /Project
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this before but 1) it's really annoying to prefix every bundle 2) I did not manage to prefix FOSUserBundle routes (especially the one for login_check). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: FOSUserBundle routes are also imported in your routing.yml and have also the `prefix` parameter.

Comment: Well, I did this: `fos_user_bundle_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
    prefix:   /Project`, cleared the cache and I get the same error

Comment: Have you added the prefix to the entries in the config/security file?

Comment: I have tried but it didn't work. I don't understand why it was made so complicated... In the end, I have returned to the previous a-bit-less-annoying way that consists in using RewriteRule to leave url to certain paths alone (`RewriteRule ^/bundles/.*$ - [L]`) and rewrite everything else to app.php (`RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]`) with my document root set to the web directory. Doing so forces me to escape all the paths that do not point to my symfony application but at least it works...